# Retrieve app data from Windows 8 Store

Tags: xml, windows-8, wireshark

I'm trying to get a the app data for the applications currently available on Windows 8. I've used WireShark to monitor the network while accessing the store to no avail. I've managed to find the image data but can't seem to edit the link to obtain the app data webpage.

Here are the links for the app tile and screenshot for two different apps:

http://wscont1.apps.microsoft.com/winstore//1x/6d5111a9-85db-46c7-ad1f-f5044684bb77/Icon.6690.png

http://wscont1.apps.microsoft.com/winstore//1x/2b74bf93-4a97-4696-b4ae-437e8cafe7b6/Screenshot.3261.10913.png

I'm looking for a webpage with the app data in XML format, similar to that of a Windows Phone 7 app:

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/apps/3a9b71b7-959c-4253-8770-1ca203d4768f

Could anybody help me discover where the rest of the data is please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A preview version of the Windows Store is avialable, however you need to know the ID of the App because there is no way to search it.

Example:

> http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-us/app/9c10bc10-75bf-41e3-a26a-01aba908af85

You can get this ID without Wireshark, just use the Store App to browse to the App, then open the Charms (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and click on *Share*. Choose the Mail App and copy the link in the body of the draft.

Comment: You can also use this link to get all the app links (I discovered): http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/sitemap/sitemap_1.xml